# What is the sum of the alternating sum of the reciprocals of the primes?

Tags: sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

So I came across this question recently. Let's form a series with prime numbers: 1/2 - 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/7 + ... As it turns out, this series converges to a value of roughly 0.2696. However, it seems like very little is known about this sum itself. I couldn't even find out any information on if it was even *rational*, but since there are an infinite amount of prime numbers, I would guess not.

Anyway, my theory is that there is a neater way to represent this mysterious number, perhaps using constants like pi or e. It's really incredible what you can do with just these numbers - for example, the sum of the series 1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4 + ... is ln 2, which is a constant with many real world applications. Even if there isn't a way to represent that prime number series, it would be nice to at least see a proof of that, instead of being left with this mystery.

Comment: I doubt that there is a “neat expression” for the sum. What you can do is to calculate the sum with (say) 10 correct digits and then look it up at the [inverse symbolic calculator](http://wayback.cecm.sfu.ca/projects/ISC/ISCmain.html).

Comment: There is some stuff at [A078437](https://oeis.org/A078437) at OEIS.

Comment: I share the doubt of Martin R , moreover it will be difficult to calculate this sum to a high precision because we cannot use methods to accelerate the convergence. Concerning the real world applications of $\ln(2)$ : This constant is just needed to convert $2^x$ into $e^{kx}$ , which has nicer properties concerning derivate and integral.

Comment: An irrationality proof of this constant will probably be extremely difficult.